# Unable to redirect from 80 to 8080 with nginx

Tags: apache, tomcat, nginx, server, port

I am unable to redirect my website from domain_name:8080 to domain_name:80

This is the code in my **/etc/nginx/sites-available/file**.

```
server {
    listen *:80;

    root /var/www/;
    server_name domain_name;

    location / {
            proxy_pass      http://127.0.0.1:8080/;
    }
}
```

What's interesting is, I am able to access it without **:8080** on LAN. I am using **com.bmuschko.tomcat** plugin with **Gradle**. Am I missing something?

Comment: What "unable" exactly means, what error do you get

Comment: Hi Dusan, I am trying to access my website without appending **8080** to the url. Tried the nginx port redirection code I have posted above but it's not working. Is there anything I am missing?

Comment: "not working" does not mean much. what exact error do you get?

Comment: I am not getting any error. nginx server is running fine. It's just that redirection is not working. for eg. when I access the website with www.domainname.com it's redirecting to page not found screen. but if I access it with www.domainname:8080.com it's redirecting me to the home page of the website.

Comment: if you are trying to open `www.domainname.com`, then in your nginx configuration you should have `server_name www.domainname.com;`

Comment: Tried it with `server_name www.domainname.com` and `domainname.com`. Still getting the same issue.